# Converting from .opus to .wav

Tags: audio, rtp, pcap, opus

Hello I am supposed to write a utility that will extract an opus encoded audio payload from RTP packets which I will read from a pcap dumpfile. The utility should also have the functionality that can be used to decode the payload that I am extracting from the rtp packets and convert it to a .wav file.
Currently I have written a code that extracts the payload from the rtp packets and dumps it into a file "log.opus". However I am stuck at this point. How should I proceed with writing the decoder logic?
I am working on Windows platform and am using winpcap library and libopus.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at this trivial example I created to show how to use Opus:

http://git.xiph.org/?p=opus.git;a=blob;f=doc/trivial_example.c

You'll want to keep just the decoder part. There's also the API documentation for more details:

http://www.opus-codec.org/docs/html_api-1.1.0/index.html